# symfony2 - assetic:dump - selective way of dumping

Tags: symfony, assetic

I'm using kriswallsmith/assetic(symfony/AsseticBundle) bundle for Symfony2, I was looking for a way to render only part of the files using assetic:dump.

I'm explain my self:
My app as some assets for admin management, and other for frontend, I would like to be able to dump only front assets, is it possible ?

this assetic:dump is also alway rendering both files for app_dev.php and app.php is there a way to tell him to render only the compiled css/js ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

In your app/config/config.yml, where you have your assetic configuration, you can add this:

```
     assetic:
         #####
         assets:
             this_is_the_name_of_the_dumpfile:
                 inputs:
                     - %kernel.root_dir%/../web/css/style.css
                     - another/path/to/another/file
                     - ######
                 filters:
                     - yui_js
                     - other_defined_filter
```

And if you configured assetic to dump files to /web/assetic/, add in your twig file the path to the dumped file: `{{ asset('assetic/this_is_the_name_of_the_dumpfile.css') }}`